# How to perform a sed in-place substitution that only creates backups of files that were changed?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, sed

I ran the following to replace a term used in all files in the current working directory:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i'.bup' -e's/Ms. Johnson/Mrs. Melbin/g'
```

This performed the word substitution but it also created `.bup` files of files that never had the `Ms. Johnson` string.

How do I perform the substitution without creating all these unnecessary backups?

Comment: seems to me as a bug of sed [see](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/bugs/534/)

Comment: There is probably a better approach possible using `ex`, and conditionally (only if the file is changed) running `:!cp '%' '%.bup'` before saving and exiting.  Might be worth looking into.

Comment: I wrote a [question about my idea above](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6901/4676) on the `vi` stack exchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could check the files' contents to make sure that a substitution will take place when `sed` operates on them:

```
find . \
    -type f \
    -exec grep -q 'Ms. Johnson' {} \; \
    -print0 |
xargs -0 sed -i'.bup' -e's/Ms. Johnson/Mrs. Melbin/g'
```

If you want to be really clever about it, you could forego using `find` at all:

```
grep -Z -l -r 'Ms. Johnson' |
    xargs -0 sed -i'.bup' -e's/Ms. Johnson/Mrs. Melbin/g'
```

Comment: I think you need a `'{}'` just before your `\;` in that `-exec`.

Answer (score 9):

Find has an `-exec` operator that executes an arbitrary command.  Even better, `-exec` is a *test*, so you can chain several `-exec`s together, and if earlier commands fail, later ones won't get executed.  The string `{}` gets replaced with the current filename, and `;` marks the end of the command.  You should quote both to avoid the shell interfering.

So:

```
find . -type f \
    -exec grep -q 'Ms. Johnson' '{}' \; \
    -exec sed -i'.bup' -e's/Ms. Johnson/Mrs. Melbin/g' '{}' \;
```

Comment: I've never had a problem using bare {}'s.

Comment: @amphetamachine: Neither have I, but the man page suggests it.  It could be a csh thing, or there might be shells (not Bash and not POSIX) who expand `{}` to the null string when doing brace expansion.

Answer (score 5):

I looked at the man page and didn't see any way to do it directly through `sed`, as I'm sure you did before asking.   I see several ways to work around this using grep, but I think the easiest is this:

```
grep -rlZ "Ms. Johnson" . | xargs -0 sed -i'.bup' -e's/Ms. Johnson/Mrs. Melbin/g'
```

`-r` recurse
`-l` print filename only
`-Z` end names with null

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you need to build a list of files that match your search terms first.

```
search="test"
for match in $(find -type f -exec grep -l $search "{}" \;)
do sed -i'.bup' -e "/$search/ s/$search/Mrs. Melbin/g" "$match"
done
```

Comment: You forgot the `.` as the first argument to `find`.  Also, as I was informed myself not too long ago, you don't actually need to quote or escape the `{}`

Comment: Don't generate a list of files and perform command substitution on that. First `find` generates a newline-separated list of files, then the shell breaks up this list at any whitespace (not just newlines) and then the shell treats each word as a glob pattern. This only works if your file names do not contain whitespace or `\[?*`. Other answers on this page show how to do this correctly.

Comment: @Kevin The `.` is unnecessary with find (at least find found on linux) because it's assumed when no path is passed an argument.